# what is the true sql statement for show something like list of products

Tags: mysql, mariadb

How can I show  the products ( `description` , `serial number`, `price` ) purchased by the customer "Peacock cafe bar" in the picture

I show  3 tables
[image: tables xampp]

I have try with

```
select 
from ...
where(
    select
    from ...
    as ...
    where 
    “”
)
```

Comment: It might help to show exactly what you've tried and what specifically went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I remember you should use joint query on your tables, something like:

```
select * from ProductsTable as Products
join  
(select Buys.ProCode from CustomerTable as Customer
join BuysTable as Buys
on Customer.code = Buys.custcode) as customerbuys
on Products.code = customerbuys.ProCode
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer .. I have tried this query but It does not work because I want to display only the  products with cust code =3 .. I have try this one 
(select Buys.ProCode* from CustomerTable as Customer join BuysTable as Buys on Customer.code = Buys.custcode=3 ) as customerbuys on Products.code = customerbuys.ProCode=3

Comment: @koutsio Why did you accept an answer that "does not work" instead of the one that "is working properly"?

Comment: I fail to see the logic of that decision.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this: You'll want to join your tables on their keys and then filter the results in the WHERE clause like so.

```
SELECT
   p.pr_serial
 , p.pr_descr
 , p.pr_price
FROM   Customers AS c
JOIN Buys AS b
    ON c.cust_code = b.cust_code
JOIN Products AS p
    ON b.pr_code = p.pr_code
WHERE  c.cust_name = 'Peacock cafe bar';
```

Comment: @koutsio Should probably accept this one then. You accepted the one that "doesn't work". Very curious.